# Can not use Custom controls of fabric js in Angular

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I'm working a project using angular as framework. I have a problem how implementing custome control of fabricjs in angular. the code is like this

```
const deleteIcon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Ebene_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='595.275px' height='595.275px' viewBox='200 215 230 470' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Ccircle style='fill:%23F44336;' cx='299.76' cy='439.067' r='218.516'/%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='267.162' y='307.978' transform='matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -222.6202 340.6915)' style='fill:white;' width='65.545' height='262.18'/%3E%3Crect x='266.988' y='308.153' transform='matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 398.3889 -83.3116)' style='fill:white;' width='65.544' height='262.179'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E";
    const deleteImg = document.createElement('img');
    deleteImg.src = deleteIcon;

    fabric.prototype.controls.deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
      x: 0.5,
      y: -0.5,
      offsetY: -16,
      offsetX: 16,
      cursorStyle: 'pointer',
      mouseUpHandler: this.deleteObject,
      render: this.renderIcon(deleteImg),
      cornerSize: 24
    });
```

the error above is Property 'Control' does not exist on type 'typeof... / @types/fabric/fabric-impl' and Property 'prototype' does not exist on type '.../@types/fabric/fabric-impl'
It seems can not use prototype and object Control,
thanks in advance

Comment: Please  look at   http://fabricjs.com/custom-control-render    On that page, please click on JS button to see code.  You could try using  fabric.Object.prototype.controls.deleteControl